# Can an SObject link to a file?

Tags: lookup, sobject, files

Is it currently natively possible to somehow have an SObject that links to a document, attachment, or salesforce file? Sure, you can always have a field that just includes the id of the object as text but that isn't really safe. I could not find any decent information about this issue, so if somebody could shine some light on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that is possible by default.

- The ContentDocumentLink does provide that functionality where it links a record with a content document.
- The attachments are linked to a parent directly (not vice-versa.)
- Documents are linked to folders, not to a record.

See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_documents.htm)

[image]

ContentNotes is also linked to a record by ContentDocumentLink

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's not possible for the time being.